# Matlab : Can Conditional plotting done in a loop be vectorized?

Tags: matlab, plot, vectorization

I am wanting to do conditional plotting of vertical lines, that change color based on the value of an integer vector.  Those values are integers that range from 0-4.

Currently, I am using a loop to go through the tables to plot the lines.  This works, but for LARGE amounts of data it takes time, and I'm wondering if it can be vectorized.

Attached is a stripped down version of the script to loop through a data vector(sample) that simply Loops through the vector, and plots a vertical line based on the value of the integer.

I will also attach the simple variable I created called 'SAMPLE' below to paste into your workspace.

```
for i=1:size(sample,1)
    if      sample(i)==1 
        line( [i i] ,[0 10], 'Marker','.','LineStyle','-','Color','r');
    elseif  sample(i)==2
        line( [i i] ,[0 10], 'Marker','.','LineStyle','-','Color','b');
    elseif  sample(i)==3
        line( [i i] ,[0 10], 'Marker','.','LineStyle','-','Color',[1 .5 0]);
    elseif sample(i)==4
        line( [i i] ,[0 10], 'Marker','.','LineStyle','-','Color','g');
    end
end
```

Variable:

```
sample=[[3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0]];
```

But is is possible to 'vectorize' plotting in this way w/o having to do it iteratively in a loop as I have done?

[image: Picture of Desired Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that when plotting a line, MATLAB will skip points whose value is `NaN`.

```
% Your vector
sample=[3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0];

% Your colors
colors = [
    1 0 0
    0 0 1
    1 .5 0
    0 1 0];

for idx = 1:4
    % Find the index of each of your integers
    X = find(sample == (idx));

    % Force X to be a row vector
    X = X(:)';

    % Stack two X's on top of one another with a third row filled
    % with NaNs. Fill in your Y values in the same way while
    % you're at it.
    Y = [zeros(size(X)); 10 + zeros(size(X)); nan(size(X))];
    X = [X; X; nan(size(X))]; %#ok<AGROW>

    % Matlab is column major. By using the colon here, you
    % produce a vector that is [X1 X1 nan X2 X2 nan ... etc.]
    X = X(:);
    Y = Y(:);

    % Draw the line
    line(X, Y, 'Marker', '.', 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', colors(idx, :))
end
```

There's still a loop, but now you're just looping over the possible values instead of looping over the each value in the vector. I think you will find that this will scale much better.

Changing input to:

```
sample = zeros(1, 1e6);
for idx = 1:4
    sample(randi(1e6, 1, 1000)) = idx;
end
```

and benchmarking with `timeit` gives a time of 0.0065706 seconds on my machine, while the OP code benchmarks at 1.4861 seconds.

Comment: Wow! That is definitely more efficient and along the lines of what I was looking for. Using the benchmark I used earlier, it took approx 3 seconds to run it.  Using that same data with this mod, it took 0.007036 seconds. So ~400x faster. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd change to something like:

```
colors=[1 0 0,
        0 1 0,
        1 0.5 0,
        0 0 1];

nnsamples=samples(samples~=0);

for ii=1:size(nnsamples,1)

        line( [ii ii] ,[0 10], 'Marker','.','LineStyle','-','Color',colors(nnsamples(ii),:));

end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will add these changes to my current script as it is a more compact form of what I was doing.  But I am still wondering if it is possible to remove the loop all together somehow to increase efficiency at which this get processed? For example testing it on 170K values, both types are processed at just over 3 seconds.

Comment: 170K plots on 3 seconds? That is fast @pelt

Comment: Your solution is slightly quicker on average.

Comment: Here is how they differ.  You can see the original and yours, and the average on the bottom.  ALong with the approximate time per calculation, ran it 5 times.  http://i.imgur.com/CsFlavW.jpg

Comment: Yes your edited version is even slightly faster than you original. You can see the times of the Original, YOUR Original, and then your edited version.  http://i.imgur.com/xJjU28i.jpg

Comment: @pelt I see. Its still a lot of plots.